# Exception in Application start method java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)

Tags: java, fxml, fxmlloader

I am having trouble finding what to fix in my fxml/java code, this is the whole error:

> java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>       at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:389)
>       at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:328)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>       at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:767)
>        Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
>       at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:917)
>       at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$154(LauncherImpl.java:182)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
>          Caused by: javafx.fxml.LoadException: No controller specified.
>         /Volumes/OSTIUM/Labs/CAPSTONE/IceCreamScene.fxml:23
>       at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2597)
>       at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.access$100(FXMLLoader.java:103)
>       at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$Element.getControllerMethodHandle(FXMLLoader.java:557)
>       at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$Element.processEventHandlerAttributes(FXMLLoader.java:599)
>       at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processEndElement(FXMLLoader.java:770)
>       at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processEndElement(FXMLLoader.java:2823)
>       at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2532)
>       at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2441)
>       at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3214)
>       at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3175)
>       at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3148)
>       at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3124)
>       at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3104)
>       at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3097)
>       at IceCreamRUN.start(IceCreamRUN.java:11)
>       at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$161(LauncherImpl.java:863)
>       at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$174(PlatformImpl.java:326)
>       at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$172(PlatformImpl.java:295)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$173(PlatformImpl.java:294)
>       at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)

I have been looking throught the 'RUN' and 'Control' code to try anf find the mistake and im not finding anything.These are the code for the 'RUN' program and the 'Control'

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class IceCreamRUN extends Application
 {
  public void start (Stage stage ) throws Exception
   {
  Parent parent = 
  FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("IceCreamScene.fxml"));
  Scene scene = new Scene(parent);
  stage.setTitle("Patino's Ice Cream Shop");
  stage.setScene(scene);
  stage.show();

   }
  public static void main(String [] args)
   {
  launch(args);
   }
}
```

---

```
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.CheckBox;
import javafx.scene.control.RadioButton;
import javafx.scene.control.ToggleGroup;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert.AlertType;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

 public class IceCreamControl {

//declarations

@FXML
private RadioButton Vanilla;

@FXML
private ToggleGroup FlavorGroup;

@FXML
private RadioButton Choc;

@FXML
private RadioButton StrwBerry;

@FXML
private Button Save;

@FXML
private Button ReDo;

@FXML
private Button Calculate;

@FXML
private CheckBox Nuts;

@FXML
private CheckBox Cherries;

double creamcost = 0.0;
double extra = 0.0;

//processing

@FXML
void CalculateListener() 
{
      double sub, tax, total;
      double taxRate = 0.06;

      sub = VanillaListener() + ChocolateListener() + 
                StrawberryListener() 
                   + ExtraListener();
      tax = sub * taxRate;
      total = sub + tax;

      Alert alert = new Alert (AlertType.INFORMATION);
      alert.setHeaderText(String.format("Total: $ %.2f", total));
      alert.setContentText(String.format("Order: $ %.2f\nTax: %.2f\n 
      Total: $ %.2f", sub, tax, total));
      alert.setTitle("Your Order");
      alert.showAndWait();
  }

@FXML
double ExtraListener() 
{
      extra = 0.0;
      if(Cherries.isSelected())
         extra += 0.50;
      if(Nuts.isSelected())
         extra += 0.50;

      return extra;
}

@FXML
void ReDoListener() throws IOException 
{
   String order;
   creamcost = 0.0;
   extra = 0.0;
   Nuts.setSelected(false);
   Cherries.setSelected(false);
   Vanilla.setSelected(false);
   Choc.setSelected(false);
   StrwBerry.setSelected(false);

   File file = new File ("IcecreamSave.txt");
   Scanner inputFile = new Scanner (file);

   while(inputFile.hasNext())
      {
         order = inputFile.nextLine();
         if (order.charAt(0) == 'v')
            {
               Vanilla.setSelected(true);
               creamcost = 2.25;
            }
         if (order.charAt(0) == 'c')
            {
               Choc.setSelected(true);
               creamcost = 2.25;
            }
         if (order.charAt(0) == 's')
            {
               StrwBerry.setSelected(true);
               creamcost = 2.25;
            }
      }
   inputFile.close();
}

@FXML
void SaveListener() throws IOException 
{
PrintWriter outputfile = new PrintWriter ("IcecreamSave.txt");

if(Vanilla.isSelected())
  outputfile.println("vanilla"); 
if(Choc.isSelected())
  outputfile.println("chocolate");
if(StrwBerry.isSelected())
  outputfile.println("strawberry");
if (Nuts.isSelected())
  outputfile.println("nuts");
if(Cherries.isSelected())
  outputfile.println("cherry");

outputfile.close();
}

@FXML
double StrawberryListener() 
{
if (StrwBerry.isSelected())
    creamcost = 2.25;
   else creamcost = 0.0;
  return creamcost;
}

@FXML
double VanillaListener() 
{
if (Vanilla.isSelected())
    creamcost = 2.25;
   else creamcost = 0.0;
  return creamcost;
}

@FXML
double ChocolateListener() 
{
if (Choc.isSelected())
    creamcost = 2.25;
   else creamcost = 0.0;
  return creamcost;
   }

}
```

I would appreciate help finding the mistake immensely.

---

---

---

Update: I fixed the location but got a new error;

```
 > Aug 15, 2018 1:28:21 PM javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement 
 processValue
 WARNING: Loading FXML document with JavaFX API of version 10.0.1 by 
 JavaFX runtime of version 8.0.171
 Exception in Application start method
 java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at
```

sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:     62)
     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImp     l.java:43)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
     at 
com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherI     mpl.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:328)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:767)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:917)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$154(LauncherImpl.java:182)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: javafx.fxml.LoadException: No controller specified.
/Volumes/OSTIUM/Labs/CAPSTONE/IceCreamScene.fxml:22

```
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2597)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.access$100(FXMLLoader.java:103)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$Element.getControllerMethodHandle(FXMLLoader.java:557)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$Element.processEventHandlerAttributes(FXMLLoader.java:599)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processEndElement(FXMLLoader.java:770)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processEndElement(FXMLLoader.java:2823)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2532)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2441)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3214)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3175)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3148)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3124)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3104)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3097)
at IceCreamRUN.start(IceCreamRUN.java:11)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$161(LauncherImpl.java:863)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$174(PlatformImpl.java:326)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$172(PlatformImpl.java:295)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$173(PlatformImpl.java:294)
at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
```

Exception running application IceCreamRUN

Answer (score 0):

The reason is in the root cause exception. It cannot find the `IceCreamScene.fxml`.
Check, that the file exists in proper location.

Your app is looking for it in this path:
`/Volumes/OSTIUM/Labs/CAPSTONE/IceCreamScene.fxml`